# Проблема со $stateProvider Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-ui-router

Имеются три $stateProvider, но работает только первый. Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? P.S. В index.html все прописано.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Libraries', ['angular-sha1', 'ui.router', 'utils', 'ngCookies']);

angular.module('Login', []);
angular.module('Dashboard', []);
angular.module('UserDashboard', []);

var app = angular.module('main', ['Login', 'Dashboard', 'Libraries','UserDashboard'])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/login').when('/', '/login');

    $stateProvider.state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: '/angular/templates/states/login.html'
        });
    $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            controller: 'DashboardController',
            templateUrl: '/angular/templates/states/dashboard.html'
        });
    $stateProvider.state('userdashboard', {
            url: '/userdashboard',
            controller: 'UserDashboardController',
            templateUrl: '/angular/templates/states/userdashboard.html'
        });

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

}).run(function ($rootScope, utils) {
});
```

Comment: нужен полноценный рабочий пример который можно открыть и запустить, например на jsfiddle или plunkr. Иначе непонятно как у вас организован остальной код, разметка и т.д.  предоставьте [краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)